# Configuring Tomcat 6 for JSON

Tags: json, tomcat

This seems like a silly question, but I haven't really seen a good guide or best practices for getting Tomcat to respond to JSON requests.  Does anyone know of one?  We'll be handling a lot of requests so I need to consider redundancy and efficiency.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Jackson oder JSON-Lib to transform your output from within your servlets/controllers.